# Matching exact string with indexOf

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, string, match

Say I have something like this:

```
[
[ 'Friend' ],
[ 'Friendship-' ],
[ 'Friends' ],
[ 'friendly' ],
[ 'friendster' ],
]
```

I want to go through this and find the field that matches "Friend", but Friend only - not Friend**s**, Friend**ship** etc. How would I do this?

I have tried indexOf() & regex match, but I am still a beginner so it always matches them all right now.

Comment: What is that data structure you are starting with. Should that all be enclosed in a larger array that you want to filter? Is it a string? It's helpful if your examples can be copied and pasted without syntax errors.

Comment: try regex `^[F|f]riend$`

Answer (score 2):

To find the index you can use [`findIndex()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)

If you might have more than one to find, you can use `filter()` which will return a list of matches. Since you want to match `Friend` and only `Friend` you can just use equality `===` to test.

Here's examples of both `findIndex` and `filter()`:

```js
let arr = [
    [ 'Friendship-' ],
    [ 'Friends' ],
    [ 'Friend' ],
    [ 'friendly' ],
    [ 'friendster', 'Friend' ]
]
// get first matching index
let idx = arr.findIndex(item => item.includes('Friend'))
console.log("Found Friend at index:", idx) // will be -1 if not found

// filter for `Friends`
let found = arr.filter(i => i.includes('Friend'))
console.log("All with friend: ", found)
```

Answer (score 1):

let say you have

```
let a = [ [ 'Friend' ], [ 'Friendship-' ], [ 'Friends' ], [ 'friendly' ], [ 'friendster' ] ]
```

then:

```
let find = (a,w)=>{let i=-1; a.map((x,j)=>{if(x[0]===w) i=j}); return i}

let index = find(a, 'Friend'); // result: 0
```

if not found then `find` returns `-1`

### UPDATE

And here is shorter version based on [Mark Meyer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53326082/860099) answer:

```
var find = (a,w)=>a.findIndex(e=>e[0]===w);  // find(a, 'Friend') -> 0
```

```js
let a = [ [ 'Friend' ], [ 'Friendship-' ], [ 'Friends' ], [ 'friendly' ], [ 'friendster' ] ]

var find = (a,w)=>a.findIndex(e=>e[0]===w); 


console.log( find(a, 'Friend') );
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few good ways to solve this problem, since you mentioned [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) This example will use a regular expression and the `test` method (which returns a boolean).  the `^` at the head of the expression tells the evaluator to only look in cases where the line starts with the expression. The `$` does the same for the end. Combined you get a line which exactly matches your search criteria.

```js
const arr = [
[ 'Friendship-' ],
[ 'Friends' ],
[ 'friendly' ],
[ 'Friend' ],
[ 'friendster' ],
]

const index = arr.findIndex(([val]) => /^Friend$/.test(val));

if (index === -1) {
  console.log('No Match Found');
  return;
}
console.log(arr[index]);
```

Answer (score 1):

If your data structure is an array of arrays with a single item of a string, you could use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```js
let items = [
  ['Friend'],
  ['Friendship-'],
  ['Friends'],
  ['friendly'],
  ['friendster']
];

items = items.filter(x => x[0] === "Friend");
console.log(items);
```